# I'm trying to call a functions inside a widget in flutter, but nothing happens

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I building an app that interacts with some android camera features using dart and flutter on Android Studio.
I'm not very experienced with Dart & Flutter, I'm still in learning process.

```dart
class SwitchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SwitchWidgetClass createState() => new SwitchWidgetClass();
}
```

Whenever I call `Torch.turnOn()` nothing is happening and I don't know why. I have tried many approaches and I'm still getting nothing.

The function I'm trying to call is from this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/torch) called torch. This package is for turning on and off the **android camera flashlight**.

The main file of this package I'm using has the following code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Torch {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('io.siteplan.flutterplugins/torch');

    static Future turnOn() => _channel.invokeMethod('turnOn');

  static Future turnOff() => _channel.invokeMethod('turnOff');

  static Future<bool> get hasTorch async => await _channel.invokeMethod('hasTorch');

  static Future flash(Duration duration) => turnOn().whenComplete(() => Future.delayed(duration, () => turnOff()));
}
```

I wrote the code that is below this statement in my custom dart file called `homepage.dart`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:torch/torch.dart';

/**
 * HomePage StatefulWidget is here!
 */

class SwitchWidgetClass extends State {
  bool switchControl = false;
  var textHolder = 'Switch is OFF';

  void toggleSwitch(bool value) {
    if (switchControl == false) {
      setState(() {
        switchControl = true;
        textHolder = 'Switch is ON';
      });
      print('Switch is ON');
      Torch.turnOn();

    } else {
      setState(() {
        switchControl = false;
        textHolder = 'Switch is OFF';
      });
      print('Switch is OFF');
      Torch.turnOff();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
      Transform.scale(
          scale: 1.5,
          child: Switch(
            onChanged: toggleSwitch,
            value: switchControl,
            activeColor: Colors.blue,
            activeTrackColor: Colors.green,
            inactiveThumbColor: Colors.white,
            inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
          )),
      Text(
        '$textHolder',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

What I want is When I call the `Torch.turnOn()` method, it should work and turn on the **camera flashlight**.

Comment: I have tested your code works fine. Hot reload won't work you have to re-install application.

Comment: Is the flashlight turning on? Because I reinstalled the app and I'm only seeing updated UI changes but the flashlight is still not turning on.

Comment: yes. flash light turning on and off. It works fine. I have samsung s7 edge andoid 9.0.

Comment: I think it's android version issue... I have tried the app in android **-v8** and anything is working fine. Earlier I was testing the app on android **-v5**. Thanks for your replies man. Oh! and do you think there is anything I can do to make this app also run on **android versions** below 7?

Comment: create your own flutter plugin if this plugin not working on all devices and in android side choose a library which works perfectly. Then communicate with flutter with method Channels.

Comment: Ok man, I understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

To use Torch you must import "torch.dart" package;A Flutter plugin to access the device's torch on Android and iOS.

> import 'package:torch/torch.dart';

[Read more here](https://pub.dev/packages/torch)

Answer (score 0):

try to add this Permission to Manifest file in Android

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```